# Add element to an XML file on Windows Phone

Tags: xml, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

How can add elements in an XML file in Windows Phone 7 using anything you want like (Linq or XmlWriter) I did it before in normal C# app but in Silverlight and WP7 is different.

The file is in the solution explorer folder ("files/IO.xml"), so no need to give answers about the IsolatedStorage.

My file is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lights>
    <light id="1" name="toto" />
    <light id="2" nom="titi" />  
</light>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is in IsolatedStorage, you can try something like this:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStore = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("IO.xml", FileMode.Open, store))
  {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(isoStore);
    doc.Descendants("lights")
       .FirstOrDefault()
       .Add(new XElement("light", new XAttribute("id","3"), new XAttribute("name","tete"))

    doc.Save(isoStore);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by "no need to give answers about the IsolatedStorage" so I left that out. You have to use IsolatedStorage. I edited the answer.

Comment: And where I should put that file, because I need sometimes to modify it manually ?

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you trying to do? I've heard of an IsolatedStorage tool for the PC. Or, maybe leave the file where it is, and copy it to IsolatedStorage during startup. I'm not sure.